# How to convert JSON object structure to dot notation?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I've got a variable I'm storing that will dictate what fields to exclude from a query:

```
excludeFields = {
  Contact: {
    Address: 0,
    Phone: 0
  }
}
```

I need to convert this to a dot notation that will work with Mongo's `findOne`, e.g.:

```
things.findOne({}, {fields: {'Contact.Address': 0, 'Contact.Phone': 0}})
```

Just passing `excludeFields` does not work and results in an error, "Projection values should be one of 1, 0, true, or false"

```
things.findOne({}, {fields: excludeFields})
```

Do I have to write my own function to convert from hierarchical structure to flat dot notation? Or is there some mechanism to do this in JavaScript that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This should be flexible enough for most needs:

```
function dotNotate(obj,target,prefix) {
  target = target || {},
  prefix = prefix || "";

  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
    if ( typeof(obj[key]) === "object" && obj[key] !== null ) {
      dotNotate(obj[key],target,prefix + key + ".");
    } else {
      return target[prefix + key] = obj[key];
    }
  });

  return target;
}
```

Run on your `excludesFields` variable like so:

```
dotNotate(excludeFields);
```

It returns the current structure:

```
{ "Contact.Address" : 0, "Contact.Phone" : 0 }
```

So you can even do, inline:

```
things.findOne({}, {fields: dotNotate(excludeFields) })
```

Or provide as a projection:

```
var projection = { "fields": {} };
dotNotate(excludeFields,projection.fields);
things.findOne({}, projection);
```

Works nicely at all depths and even with arrays in an essential way, unless you need operators like `$push`.

Comment: null values are also treated as object in javascript

Comment: this will skip Date objects: You can add a separate check for this, e.g.
`typeof(val) === "object" && val !== null && !(val instanceof Date)`

Answer (score 3):

I use a function pretty much similar to the accepted answer

```
    function convertJsonToDot(obj, parent = [], keyValue = {}) {
      for (let key in obj) {
        let keyPath = [...parent, key];
        if (obj[key]!== null && typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
            Object.assign(keyValue, convertJsonToDot(obj[key], keyPath, keyValue));
        } else {
            keyValue[keyPath.join('.')] = obj[key];
        }
    }
    return keyValue;
}
```

Here, I do an additional check 'obj[key] !== null' because **unfortunately** null is also of type 'object'.

I actually wanted to add this a comment to the accepted answer but couldn't because of not enough reputation.

Comment: Might be better if you explicitly wrote obj[key] !== null rather than just checking that obj[key] is truthy for clarity

Comment: Agreed. Edited my answer

Comment: I know this is old but, if you operate on an array it turns that into dot notation. If you save that to mongo without an array to save to it saves it like an object.

Comment: this will skip Date objects: You can add a separate check for this, e.g.
`typeof(val) === "object" && val !== null && !(val instanceof Date)`

Answer (score 1):

```
var fields = {};
for (var k in excludeFields) {
  for (var p in excludeFields[k]) {
    fields[k + '.' + p] = excludeFields[k][p];
  }
}
```

Then:

```
things.findOne({}, {fields: fields})
```