# dynamic query mongodb javascript

Tags: mongodb-query

I have a collection of images in MongoDB. Documents are like this:

```
{
    "image-file": "test.jpg",
    "name": {
        "es": [{ "keyword": "comida", "downloads": 0 },
            { "keyword": "cena",  "downloads": 0 }
        ],
        "en": [{ "keyword": "lunch",  "downloads": 0 },
            { "keyword": "dinner",  "downloads": 0 }
        ]
    },
    "status": "publish",

}
```

I make http request so getting so I would like to get all the image document by keyword & locale.

I got the other document with a query like this:

```
db.pictograms.find({ "name.es.keyword" : "comida"});
```

However I'm enable to make it in a dynamic way. Using Mongo Shell:

```
> var locale="es"
> var keyword="comida"
> var query = {"name": {[locale]: {"keyword":keyword}} }
> query
{ "name" : { "es" : { "keyword" : "comida" } } }
> db.pictograms.find(query)
>// NO DATA :-(
```

However if the query is simpler, this method does work:

```
> var query={}
> var campo="imagen"
> var value="test.jpg"
> query[campo]=value
test.jpg
> query
{ "imagen" : "test.jpg" }
> db.pictograms.find(query)
> //DATA OK :-)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I'm not using dot notation the find method shoud be exact.
I can convert to dot notation using [How to convert JSON object structure to dot notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33005575/how-to-convert-json-object-structure-to-dot-notation)

so now it works :-)