# Convert JSON array of objects to dot notataion

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb

I have a JSON object retrieved from a mongo doc like:

```
{
"ipv4": {
         "enable": "yes",
         "rule": [
             {
                "flow": {
                    "destinationAddress": "0.0.0.0"
                }
            },
            {
                "flow": {
                    "destinationAddress": "2.2.2.2"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I'd like  to convert it to this:

```
{
    "ipv4.enable": "yes",
    "ipv4.rule.0.flow.destinationAddress": "0.0.0.0",
    "ipv4.rule.1.flow.destinationAddress": "2.2.2.2"
}
```

My problem premise is concentrated around an array containing objects/array of objects within it.

I belive this might requre recursion at some level. What would be a good way to achieve the above? I came accross [this npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-dot-notation) that comes close to doing what I need, but it does not *dot-notate* an array directly.

At the moment, I do not have any working/semi working code to show, but I will update this question if I get something to work in the right direction.

Could someone point me to some logic for getting this orking? I don't mind using any available npm packages.

Comment: This looks like what you need https://www.npmjs.com/package/flat Just google for "npm flatten json"

Comment: @TuanAnhTran An npm package seems like overkill when a simple function will do. Look at the [marked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33005742/2313887). Works at all depths.

Comment: @TuanAnhTran - Thanks for this. It's exactly what I was looking for. Although, I will look at the simple function as well.

Comment: Here is the solution in plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/WhAUssNQoxl61sqJdZ1K (please upvote)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use this as a starting point (did this during lunch and haven't proof tested it thoroughly)

```js
var data = {
"ipv4": {
         "enable": "yes",
         "rule": [
             {
                "flow": {
                    "destinationAddress": "0.0.0.0"
                }
            },
            {
                "flow": {
                    "destinationAddress": "2.2.2.2"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};

function dotnotate(data,prefix,dest){
  prefix = prefix || "";
  dest = dest || {};
  var type = typeof(data);
  
  switch(type){
    case "object":
      if(Array.isArray(data)){
        data.forEach(function(item, i){
          var tmpPrefix = prefix.length>0?prefix+"."+i:prefix+i;
          dotnotate(item,tmpPrefix,dest);
        });
      }else{
        Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key,i){
          var tmpPrefix = prefix.length>0?prefix+"."+key:prefix+key;
          dotnotate(data[key],tmpPrefix,dest);
        });
      }
    break;
    case "undefined":
      return;
    default:
      dest[prefix]=data;
  }
  return dest;
     
}

console.log(dotnotate(data))
```

Comment: Thanks Chirag. I will check this out out. It's along similar lines of the duplicate question's [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33005742/1745073)